# Declaring multiple objects of same class?

Tags: flutter, dart

is there a fancier way for writing this :

```
  TextEditingController ectrl = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passctrl = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController fnamectrl = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lnamectrl = TextEditingController();
```

I mean come-ooon !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var ectrl = TextEditingController(),
        passctrl = TextEditingController(),
        fnamectrl = TextEditingController(),
        lnamectrl = TextEditingController();
```

```
    var ctrls = List.generate(4, (index) => TextEditingController());
```